# How many strange planks are there to collect?

Tags: hammerwatch

How many strange planks are there to collect? Are they all needed to escape the castle? If not, how many do you actually need?

Bonus: provide a list of what floors the planks can be found on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 12 strange planks in the game.
You need all 12 of them to escape the castle.

I found this on the steam community really quik: [All Secrets](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=171395205)

> From the site:
>
> - Floor 1: Secret 3
> - Floor 2: Secret 7
> - Floor 3: Secret 6
> - **Floor 4: See floor 6!**
> - Floor 5: Secret 2
> - Floor 6: Secret 1; Secret 2
> - Floor 7: Secret 4
> - Floor 8: Secret 2, Secret 4
> - **Floor 9: See floor 8!**
> - Floor 10: Secret 1
> - Floor 11: Secret 5
> - Floor 12: Secret 1

Comment: It doesn't list 14 planks, there are no planks on the 4th and 9th floors. However, there are 2 planks on floor 6 and another 2 on floor 8

Comment: you're right, it does look like there are only 12. I was misreading the page. There is actually a plank on floor 4, but you reach it from a secret on floor 6.

Comment: Ah ok. Well, enjoy the game!